# Can't plot rotated region

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, plotting

I was experimenting with the code from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55288/3066) when I ran into another problem with regions.

```
Ω = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], Rectangle[{4, 4}, {8, 8}]];
RegionPlot[Ω]
```

[image: plot]

```
Ω1 = TransformedRegion[Ω, RotationTransform[45 °, {5, 5}]];
RegionQ[Ω1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
RegionPlot[Ω1]
```

> RegionPlot::invplotreg: TransformedRegion[RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], Rectangle[{4, 4}, {8, 8}]], TransformationFunction[...]] is not a valid region to plot. >>

What is the difference between a "valid region to plot" and a region that satisfies `RegionQ`? Or, perhaps, to put it better, am I seeing a bug in `RegionPlot` or just an incomplete implementation?

I note that

```
RegionPlot[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[45 °, {.5, .5}]], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

works as expected, so it would seem `RegionPlot` can handle rotations for some class of inputs.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Might try tracing it some time later (for testing my tracer :)

Comment: For me even the first basic example in the `TransformedRegion` documentation doesn't work properly. And the second example hangs the kernel...

Comment: @SimonWoods For the first example, looks like it can use a `PlotRange -> All`. (+1)

Comment: @SimonWoods, if you could send this and your OS version to the support that would be useful to track it down. Thanks. I have filed fact that an expr with `Head` `TransformedRegion` does not work as a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: @user21. re: "an expr with Head TransformedRegion does not work." I don't think that is the issue since `TransformedRegion[Rectangle[],
 RotationTransform[45 °, {.5, .5}]]` has head `TransformedRegion`, but can be plotted by `RegionPlot`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, interesting. In any case it's filed as a bug/suggestion and will be looked at.

Comment: @user21, email sent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
r1 = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], 
   Rectangle[{4, 4}, {8, 8}]];
r2 = TransformedRegion[r1, RotationTransform[45 \[Degree], {5, 5}]];
mr = DiscretizeRegion[r2]
```

[image]

And then:

```
RegionPlot[mr]
```

[image]