# Plotting a transformed region only works with integer inputs

Tags: plotting

I can't figure out why the following code only works with integers.

```
r1 = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], TranslationTransform[{0, 1, 0}]]
RegionPlot3D[r1]
DiscretizeRegion[r1]
RegionQ[r1]
```

[image][image]

now, If I replace every "1" with a  "1.", I get an error message.

```
r1 = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1., -1., -1.}, {1., 1., 1.}], TranslationTransform[{0, 1,0}]]
RegionPlot3D[r1]
DiscretizeRegion[r1]
RegionQ[r1]
```

[image]

The problem seems to extend to most of mathematica's new region functions, as demonstrated below with RegionMeasure. A possible work around is to symbolically evaluate the expression first.

```
r1 = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1., -1., -1.}, {1, 1, 1}],TranslationTransform[{0, 1, 0}]];
RegionMeasure[r1]

r1 = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-a, -a, -a}, {a, a, a}], TranslationTransform[{0, 1, 0}]];
RegionMeasure[r1] /. a -> 1.0
```

[image]
[image]

Has anybody else experimented with this issue?

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 7.

Comment: `RegionPlot` is known to have problems with `TransformedRegion`. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55298/3066). I suspect something similar is going on with `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: Confirmed on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 8.1. You should report this to *WRI*.

Comment: Yes, most likely the same problem, please report this to the support.

Comment: Even the examples from ref/TransformedRegion (online documentation) are not working out: If you execute those, you will get different or no output regions.

The region functionality must be considered heavily bugged to the point of being practically unusable in my Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this has been fixed in version 10.3.1 on Win7-64: [output with `1.`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zmWJ6.png).

Comment: @MarcoB is there a consensus on how to deal with fixed version-related bugs? It might be useful for users of pre-10.3.1 to know that this has been dealt with...