# TransformedRegion and RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, regions, geometric-transform

I encountered an issue using `RegionPlot` together with rotated regions. Notice how as long as one drags a slider in this simple `Manipulate` the plot behaves as one would expect, but reevaluates as soon as the slider is let go (and takes an suspiciously long time doing whatever it does). This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55298/cant-plot-rotated-region) might, or might not be relevant (using `DiscretizeRegion` does not fix anything in this case however).

```
parabola[a_, b_] = ImplicitRegion[x - b y^2 > a, {x, y}]

Manipulate[RegionPlot[
TransformedRegion[parabola[a, b], 
RotationTransform[w, {a, 0}]], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-3, 3}}], 
{a, 1, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {w, -45°, 45° }]
```

Comment: I get the same, however evaluation takes about 2secs and evaluates to a slightly different result than before evaluation. Most importantly, changes in `w` are reversed after evaluation. `Linux, 10.4 64bit, 16gb RAM, NVidia` I had to quit kernel 2 times before it rendered properly, but that's I think a Linux-NVidia issue.

Comment: I get this crashing my kernel if I move the `b` slider.  I can actually get the kernel to quit even without using `Manipulate` just by evaluating `RegionPlot[
 TransformedRegion[ImplicitRegion[x - .5 y^2 > 1, {x, y}], 
  RotationTransform[\[Pi]/4, {1, 0}]], PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-3, 3}}]`  - I'm on version 10.3.1 Mac